# Save a dom-to-image jpg fixed size

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that exports a table element as a JPG using the dom-to-image library.

```
domtoimage.toJpeg(document.getElementById('my-node'), { quality: 0.95 })
.then(function (dataUrl) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'my-image-name.jpeg';
    link.href = dataUrl;
    link.click();
});
```

How to make all saved images have one fixed size?

Answer (score 0):

won't such css rules help?

```
img {
    object-fit: cover;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```